# python if statements with strings

Tags: python

```
Name=str(input("Your name is? "))
print("Hello,",Name,"!")
Age=int(input("And how old might you be? "))
print("So you are",Age,"years old?")
print("So on your next birthday, you will be",Age+1,"?")
agecorrect=str(input("Yes or no? "))
yes= in ["Yes","yes","Y","y","yes.","Yes."]
no= in ["No","no","N","n","no.","No."]
if agecorrect=yes:
    print("Yes, I was right!")
else
if agecorrect=no:
    realage=int(input("So your real age on your next birthday will be? "))
    print("So you're actually going to be",realage,"? Good to know!")
else
print("I don't understand... I asked for a yes or no answer.")
```

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but I don't know why my code isn't working and I need some help. Thanks. (Python 3.5.1 by the way)

Comment: The error message will be telling you clearly that you have invalid syntax in `yes= in...`.

Comment: `in ["Yes","yes","Y","y","yes.","Yes."]` What is that?

Comment: @MarounMaroun it's all the possible answers for yes

Comment: @SirParselot - sure.. but the syntax isn't valid

Comment: Variables hold values, not partial blocks of syntax.

Comment: @cricket_007 it should be an if statement but I was just referring to the section in question. Or is that supposed to assign a block of code to a variable?

Comment: I have a suggestion on how to do your Python development, to avoid these "I don't know what's wrong!" moments. Do it one line at a time. Type in one line, run the script, see if it works as you expect. Run it in the interactive interpreter (IDLE?) where you can inspect your variables after the script runs. Use print statements to output things you're interested in. When you get to a line where it's not behaving as you expect, now you know exactly what's breaking it. If you can't figure out why, post this line (+maybe 2 context lines) on stackoverflow, with what you expected, and any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set a variable to a comparison expression like `in [...]`. So

```
yes= in ["Yes","yes","Y","y","yes.","Yes."]
```

is not not valid. You should just set `yes` and `no` to the lists:

```
yes = ["Yes","yes","Y","y","yes.","Yes."]
no = ["No","no","N","n","no.","No."]
```

then you can use `if agecorrect in yes`:

```
if agecorrect in yes:
    print("Yes, I was right!")
elif agecorrect in no:
    realage=int(input("So your real age on your next birthday will be? "))
    print("So you're actually going to be",realage,"? Good to know!")
else:
    print("I don't understand... I asked for a yes or no answer.")
```

You were also missing the `:` after `else`.

Comment: Thanks very much, and sorry about the bad question

Comment: @Nezzeh That's fine, it's more important to lean from your mistakes and improve your future posts.

Comment: `elif` rather than `else if`?

Comment: @LexyStardust Yeah, I realised that myself and went for it.

Answer (score 3):

So...

This is your "fixed" code:

```
# don't use uppercase in variables names,
# prefer underscores over camelCase or dashes
# leave space before and after assignment, there are exceptions of this rule
# but not here ;)
name = str(input("Your name is? "))
print("Hello {}!".format(name))
age = int(input("And how old might you be? "))

# english grammar man!
print("So are you {} years old?".format(age))
print("So on your next birthday, you will be {}?".format(age + 1))
agecorrect = str(input("Yes or no? "))

# in is keyword and you use it to check whether item is in collection
# or its not
# please don't try to attach it to variable
# also use space after putting comma
yes = ["Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "yes.", "Yes."]
no = ["No", "no", "N", "n", "no.", "No."]
if agecorrect in yes:
    print("Yes, I was right!")

# you forgot about colon
elif agecorrect in no:
    realage = int(input("So your real age on your next birthday will be? "))
    print("So you're actually going to be {}? Good to know!".format(realage))
else:
    print("I don't understand... I asked for a yes or no answer.")
```

Comment: Thanks for that - also the 'you are' is intended as a statement, not a question

Answer (score 2):

```
yes = ("Yes","yes","Y","y","yes.","Yes.")
question = input("Yes or no? ")
agecorrect = question in yes
if agecorrect:
    # ...
```

Comment: You can also do `agecorrect = question in yes`

Comment: @ForceBru, edited, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checks should always be done with `==`, not `=`, which is assignment.

Always use

```
if y == 'yes':
```

instead of

```
if y = 'yes':
```

Python will throw you an error if you write the code above, but other languages will simply assign the value to `y` and run the if statement.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll keep it in mind